# how to prevent from wordpress load when running my custom php script file

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, jquery

Hi guys im running a php script with AJAX .post, the script is running but the problem is that the returned call from the .post , returns the entire wordpress page and not just the data my script returned. its like the page is loaded again when im calling the script.

this ajax call is loacted within single-post.php

```
$.ajax({ url: 'localhost/check/checkuser.php',
     data: {action: window.myId},
     type: 'post',
     success: function(output) {
                  alert(output);
              }
});
```

and checkuser.php

```
$userid = $_POST['action'];

//$userid = 'zivvv';

 $oMySQL = new MySQL();
 $query = "Select share FROM videotable WHERE uid = '$userid'";
 $oMySQL->ExecuteSQL($query);
 $bb = $oMySQL->iRecords;
 $aa = $oMySQL->aResult;

  if ($bb == 0){
$query = "INSERT INTO videotable VALUES ('','$userid','true')";
$oMySQL->ExecuteSQL($query);
echo 'true';
return 'true';
 }else{
$sharing = mysql_result($aa,0,"share");
echo $sharing;
return $sharing;
 }
```

Im new to PHP and from what ive seen the returned call, simply returns everything that on the "screen", so when the wordpress page loads with the checkuser.php file, it sends the enture page back, what can I do about it?

10X ahead guys

Comment: Are you including any wordpress files in your checkuser.php script? If so, probably adding an exit(); after the `echo $sharing;` would do the trick. But if you're including wordpress files then you probably also want to use some wordpress classes (especially for the database).

Comment: Also, please read more about MySQL injection (you don't seem to check `$userid` anywhere): http://shiflett.org/articles/sql-injection

Comment: Im not including any wordpress files in the script, but from some reason when i run the script the entire page loads with it.

Answer (score 1):

some advise:

1. for database actions use `global $wpdb` http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb
2. Your script isn't protected against [sql injection](http://codex.wordpress.org/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks)
3. for ajax calls in wordpress I advise you use  the ajax script WP has http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins
4. make a (simple plugin from this) http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin
   example:

`wp-content/plugins/userchecker.php` (your file)

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: user checker
Description: A brief description of the Plugin.
Version: 0.9
*/

//your code
?>
```

This way you can execute and activate your own code with in a good WP manner.
All build in WP functions and classes will be available so you won't need to include any WP files

Comment: 10x ill try that!. I thought that there might be a specific location to place these scripts. I still dont understand why the entire page loads again when I run the script.

Comment: This may seem like a bit much if you are a beginning PHPer but it will benefit you in the long term.